# Integer from non-linear Hexadecimal Response

Tags: python, hex

I'm talking to a PLC via Serial and their specification doesn't describe any formula for obtaining the value from the hex response. I'm writing a Python script to deal with the response.

I believe the end result is a signed integer, "short" in C++ and the specification mentioned LSB/MSB in the SEND message, but I'm not sure if this applies to the response.

Here are some of the values I'm working with:

```
18 FD = -744
20 FF = -224
07 00 = 7    (parsed OK)
0A 00 = 10   (parsed OK)
64 00 = 100  (parsed OK)
36 01 = 310  (parsed OK)
B0 04 = 1200 (parsed OK)
A4 06 = 1700 (parsed OK)
```

At the moment my calculations correctly parse up to `FF 00`, but not knowing the correct formula means values above 255 remain a mystery.

Edit: After writing the question it became apparent. The hex bytes need to be reversed. Now the negative values are unknown.

If needed, the specification can be found **[here](http://www.unitronics.com/Data/Uploads/communication/Unitronics%20PCOM%20Protocol.pdf)**.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Do you not understand how to get, say, the value 310 from `36 01`?

Comment: It's the negative values which stump me, I'm not sure where the high number "stops" and becomes a negative number. Just a formula in Python is what I'm looking for.

Comment: It looks like the two negative numbers are an overflow of a word value, and it's just a simple byte reversal. (`0xFD18` as a word is `-744` decimal, `0xFF20` = -224` decimal when stored in a word, tested quickly in Windows Calculator in programmer's mode.) This also works correctly for the `0x0136` = `310` conversion.

Comment: Don't we all love Programmer mode :) My colleague pointed out if the first binary bit is 1 it should be negative.

Answer (score 2):

Negative numbers appear to be encoded using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).  Roughly, if the most significant bit of the number is set, you have to subtract 2^16 to get the "real" value.